# JMeter - Firing different requests in every iteration

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am currently using JMeter to simulate 5 users firing requests every 40 seconds. I have created 100 different requests but after every 40 seconds, each user is firing all 100 requests. I want to make it in such a way that after every 40 seconds, each user only fires 1 request and that request has to be different from the previous request. I would like to know what kind of controller to use (or anything else) to achieve this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use [Random Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller).

The simplest way to implement your scenario:

```
Thread Group
Number of Threads = 5
Loop Count = N
    . . .
    Random Controller
        HTTP Request 001
        HTTP Request 002
        HTTP Request 003
        . . .
        . . .
        HTTP Request 100
    Test Action
    Target = Current Thread
    Action = Pause
    Duration = 40000
    . . .
```

This will iterate 5 threads N times.
Random Controller will RANDOMLY pick up on each step http request from "requests pool" - all the samplers added as children to Random Controller.
Test Action will pause thread for 40 secs.

**Updated:**
working illustration for above scheme:

[image: Random Controller example]

```
Thread Group
Number of Threads = 5
Ramp-Up Period = 0
Loop Count = 10

Constant Timer
Thread Delay (in ms) = 40000
```

You can download working example for described scheme from here: [rc-plan.jmx](http://www.filehat.com/en/file/27104/rc-plan-jmx.html).
This one works how you want (at least for me, Jmeter 2.5.1): it picks randomly ONE request from requests pool (in example - 10 requests) for EACH user (here - 5 users) on EACH step (here - 10 loops) and pauses each thread for 40 secs (Constant Timer).

You can also look into this mailing archive: [Is their a way to randomize URL selection?](http://www.mail-archive.com/jmeter-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg25913.html).
Situation similar to your one seems to be described [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/jmeter-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg25916.html).

...As per official documentation *"Interactions between multiple controllers can yield complex behavior. This is particularly true of the Random Controller."*

Comment: Will the above setup make each thread fire one request(randomly picked from the requests pool) every 40 seconds or all 100 requests every 40 seconds? I tried it and it was still firing all 100 every 40 seconds. Would it be possible for you to send me a sample test plan that works for you? Thanks a lot for your help Alies

Comment: Try this one: http://www.filehat.com/en/file/27104/rc-plan-jmx.html. Works fine as for me (Jmeter 2.5.1).

Answer (score 6):

Another option for you may be to create a CSV file with parameters for your requests ahead of time and use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to parameterize a single http request.

That obviously depends on how different your http requests are, but if it fits your requirements there are some potential bonuses with maintaining 1 http request in your test plan vs. 100.

The other details would be the same as @Alies Belik laid out -- one thread group configured for your required number of threads and loops, with a constant timer at the end for your 40 second pause.